# calling actionPerformed() of a button explicitly

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I have one class where there are certain swing components.
In second class (as per requirement), I need to simulate the button click event ultimately calling the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)`. This button is in the first class(described in the first line).

How do I do so?

I have tried to go through the `fireActionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)` . However, I am unable to come to a solution. 
A small snippet (as an example) would be very much helpful.

**EDIT
Note:** I also need to disable the button, when I click it or simulate its click.

Pardon me if this has already been asked before. Though I have searched for similar question before.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: Can you provide some code with your problem?

Answer (score 8):

JButton has doClick() method but it's better to define one doMyAction() method and call it from both places.

Comment: a part of doMyAction() requires the button to be disabled. That is
    button.setEnabled(false);
Pardon me to put up an incomplete question.