# Can I call ActionPerformed method from an Event Handler class for JButton?

Tags: java, button, user-interface, event-handling, actionlistener

I have a JButton titled "select"
In the class that creates that JButton and other classes, I want to use an if condition with ActionPerformed method.

Something like(pseudo-code)

```
if(_selectListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent)) { //i.e., if select Button is clicked,
    //do something
}
```

Is this possible?

I want to call this method because I have to handle a situation in which a player should be able to choose something by clicking "select" button, or another "scroll" button, and I want to control it using something similar to a bunch of if statements like the one above.

If it is possible, what is the syntax for it? What is the argument ActionEvent?
Thank you!

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489387/calling-actionperformed-of-a-button-explicitly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and cleanest way is to add a dedicated, specific action listener to each button. That way, when the actionPerformed() method is called, you're sure that the associated button has been clicked, and don't need to test which button has been clicked:

```
selectButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // handle click on select button
    }
});

scrollButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // handle click on scroll button
    }
});
```

Another way is to use a common ActionListener, and use the `getSource()` method of ActionEvent to know which component triggered the event. Compare the result with each potential button to determine which is the one that has been clicked:

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == selectButton) {
            // handle click on select button
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == scrollButton) {
            // handle click on scroll button
        }
    }
```

*What is the argument ActionEvent?*

The answer is in [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html#actionPerformed%28java.awt.event.ActionEvent%29). Read it.

Answer (score 0):

no you cant call, `if` needs `boolean` expression/value, but this method returns void.